# develope 2 angular project into subfolder

Tags: angular, apache

1-I have an angular project and develope it to my host that work fine . (http://offan.ir)

2-I created a folder in my host . (/magazine)

3-I create another project (magazine website) and develope it into this folder

now when I run http://offan.ir/magazine

it return to http://offan.ir

How can I fix it ?

first project source is in my public_html

```
public_html/
   index.html
   main-es2015.js
   main-es2015.js.map
   main-es5.js
   main-es5.js.map
   polyfills-es2015.js.map
   polyfills-es5.js
   polyfills-es5.js.map
   .....
   magazine/
               index.html
               main-es2015.js
               main-es2015.js.map
               main-es5.js
               main-es5.js.map
               polyfills-es2015.js.map
               polyfills-es5.js
               polyfills-es5.js.map
               .....
```

Comment: can you provide your `app.routing.module.ts` file?

Comment: What type of server do you use? Your server is configured to send all requests to http://offan.ir probably because that's the default for angular apps.

Comment: Hossein Mousavi - Can you say more?

Comment: Thomas Sablik - how can I fix it?

Comment: There are dozens of different servers, each with a different type of configuration. How could we help you without this information?

Comment: Linux - Apache server

Comment: Please provide you Apache configuration and htaccess files. Somewhere in your configuration are rewrite rules and you have to add an exception and new rules for `/magazine`.

Comment: Only I want deploy second project inside of magazin/ folder

Comment: As I said that's not possible. To serve single page applications on a server like Apache https you have to redirect the requests. Here is an example https://gist.github.com/santthosh/7dabf08fa3859361ef1e. Currently all requests are send to your root project. You have to change these rules. This can't be solved in Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding subfolder name to first of any script resources in index.html